# N/record: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')

Tags: jestjs, netsuite

Can someone help me figure out why `record.create()` in my test is returning `undefined`? There are no errors reported when `record.create()` is called. But when I try to set a value in the new record, I get the error below.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')

The full test failure is below.

```
 FAIL  __tests__/customer.test.js
  ● Customer module › handles beforeSubmit() on CREATE

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')

      4 |   it('handles beforeSubmit() on CREATE', () => {
      5 |     var newRecord = record.create({type: record.Type.CUSTOMER});
    > 6 |     newRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'comments', value: 'TODO'});
        |               ^
      7 |     
      8 |     // TODO: Test something useful
      9 |   });

      at Object.setValue (__tests__/customer.test.js:6:15)
```

Below is the `__tests__/customer.test.js` file in my project.

```js
import record from 'N/record';

describe('Customer module', () => {
  it('handles beforeSubmit() on CREATE', () => {
    let newRecord = record.create({type: record.Type.CUSTOMER});
    newRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'comments', value: 'TODO'});
    
    // TODO: Test something useful
  });
});
```

Comment: I could try to help, if you provided some background on where this record.create() is defined. It looks like you are using a testing framework, where NS API is mocked, but I've never encountered such a thing

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Dmitry. `record.create()` is [the native method in the N/record module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267258059.html). I thought that since I could import it into a test that I'd be able to use `record.create()` just like it's used in a deployed script, but perhaps that's not actually the case...

Comment: It's either a bug, since the docs clearly say that the nRecord.create() returns an instance of nRecord.Record, which is definitely not undefined. Or you have some big misconceptions on where your code is executed. I'd bet 8 against 2 for the latter. I've never heard that SuiteScript supports ECMA modules, which your code apparently relies on (since you have the `import` statements). Which means your code is likely not run on NS servers, but somewhere else. And this `import record from 'N/record';` provides you with who knows what.

Comment: I'd first figure out where you run your code. If it's NS servers, then file a bug report. If it's not, look into the docs of that environment, you are using

Comment: Intuitively it looks like you are using some kind of a framework for unit testing SuiteScripts. With SuiteScript API mocked for your code. If that was correct, then it's a bug in that tool

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov thanks for the comments. The framework is NetSuite's official package: [SuiteCloud Unit Testing](https://github.com/oracle/netsuite-suitecloud-sdk/tree/master/packages/unit-testing).

Comment: The docs say that you are supposed to mock the behavior yourself https://github.com/oracle/netsuite-suitecloud-sdk/tree/master/packages/unit-testing#nrecord-module-example because on its own all those methods: create etc. are just stubs. It's not a bug, its expected. But I have problems with understanding your approach: what and how are you trying to test? What's the point to create a record in a test? **You don't expect this to fire a UserEvent script, don't you?**